# Google StreetView Smooth Navigation

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-street-view

When navigating on StreetView, Google applies an effect to the images that is being rendered to smoothly swap between then. See images bellow. The 2nd shows the effect being applied.

[image: Image 1 - Just before effect being applied]
[image: Image 2 - Effect being applied]
[image: Image 3 - Just after effect applied]

So, my question is:
How could I apply this same effect on my application?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for this answer too, but it seem like is not available for custom panoramas.

Here a similar question:
[Google Maps - Switching between Street View Panorama locations smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943112/google-maps-switching-between-street-view-panorama-locations-smoothly)

But what bother me is that I know that : https://walkinto.in/ can do this smooth transition, I have been trying to check the code of the page but nothing...

Answer (score 1):

I really want  to solve this, so I made a little proof of concept

https://jsfiddle.net/SaulBurgos/k0k5h7uu/4/

```
    .widget-scene-canvas {
      transition: 1s -webkit-filter linear,transform 1s;
    }

   .googleAnimation {
     filter: blur(1rem);
     transform: scale(1.5);
    }
```

What I do not know how to do is , start the transition when the arrows are clicked or touch on mobiles.

Could anyone improve this code ?