# Google Maps - Switching between Street View Panorama locations smoothly

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple [map proof of concept](https://map-proof-of-concept.herokuapp.com/) where, similar to maps.google.com I have a slider at the bottom of the page with street views / panos. When you click on the image it takes you to the same street view.

How can I achieve the same kind of transition effect used by google when they transition from one street view to another? Its really smooth avoids a lot of the jerky tile rerendering I'm currently experiencing.

Heres the [GitHub Repo](https://github.com/JDillon522/map-proof-of-concept) if it'll help.

Comment: umm... I think, with the API, you might not able to do it.. notice that the transition on steetview on google maps streetview API are not animated too. But you might able to play with the size, opacity, and the javascript timer to create some similar effect...

Comment: Possibly, which would make me sad. Something tells me though that its built into the API and it either isnt documented, or not publicly advertised. I'm starting to find a number of small things like that in the Google Maps extravaganza.

Comment: I haven't found a way to do this in the API, so when I want a smooth transition, I have been using the Google Street View Image API to grab the two views that I want to transition between.  I can determine when both the images have loaded (not sure if this works in older browsers), and do the transition in an overlay on top of the pano.  In your case you can cache the "to" images.  You could try that, if you don't find a better answer.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried maybe making 2 map containers, then load the other one and fade in while fading out the other an toggle back and forth when changing them.

Comment: Potentially. After playing with Google Map's street view it seems like they are just doing some sort of blur and stretch animation. I wonder if its reasonable to hack this by having one container for the first street view, overlay a street view image of that exact location, blur and stretch that image, and in the background load the new location on the original street view, and then hide the street view images. If you can point me to a good place that'll school me on those sort of transitions (blurring and stretching) I'll give you the bounty.

Comment: could you just use jQuery, to fade in and fade out the parent containers as needed ...

Comment: Possibly. But thats not the effect I'm really going for.

Comment: what effect are you going for - i think the blurring you are talking about is from progressive download of the image, where it starts out blurry then , gets more clear. For example -

Comment: Let's say the image is downloading and you've received 1/4 of the image data. For a standard jpeg, that means you'll see roughly the top quarter of the image. For a progressive jpeg, that means you might see the entire image, but it'll be "out of focus".

Comment: or just create a bunch of pre loaded instances of the maps and show them as needed - position them absolute, -99999px . then back into display when needed .