# Google Maps Api smooth transition

Tags: javascript, google-maps

For some reason in the google maps iframe embed the transition when traversing through a indoor panorama works, however when I use the google maps api it jumps to the next position with no smooth transition animation.

This is my code using the api.

And jsfiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/anders_kitson/zf551fks/1/
in the js fiddle you can see how the embed performs differently then the api.

```
var panoramaService = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

      panoramaService.getPanoramaById('SNfryT3txl4AAAQvPBGv7w', function (res, stat) {
          var loc = res.location.latLng;
          var panoramaOptions = {
              position: loc,
              pov: {
                  heading: -80,
                  pitch: 0
              },
              visible: true,
              scrollwheel: false,
              addressControl: false,
              // draggable: false,
              panControl: true,
              zoomControl: false


          };
          var panorama1 = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano1'), panoramaOptions);
          panorama1.setPano(res.location.pano);
          // alert(loc.lat()+','+loc.lng());
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the natural behavior of the API. You can try filing this as a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry) to have a simpler approach of changing the behaior of the transition from position to position. See this related question about this: [Switching between Street View Panorama locations smoothly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29943112/google-maps-switching-between-street-view-panorama-locations-smoothly),

Also you can check the [Release Notes](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/releases) about the StreetView.

Hope it helps.